# tm loses the metadata when applying tm_map

Tags: r, metadata, tm

I have a (small) problem with the tm r library.
say I have a corpus:

```
# boilerplate
bcorp <- c("one","two","three","four","five")
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(bcorp), list(lanuage = "en_US"))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus)
Docs(tdm)
```

Result:

```
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```

This works. But when I try to use a transformation tm_map():

```
# this does not work
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(bcorp), list(lanuage = "en_US"))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, tolower)
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus)
```

Gives

```
Error: inherits(doc, "TextDocument") is not TRUE
```

The solution proposed in this case was to transform to PlainTextDocument.

```
# this works but erase the metadata
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(bcorp), list(lanuage = "en_US"))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, tolower)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, PlainTextDocument)
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus)
Docs(tdm)
```

Result:

```
[1] "character(0)" "character(0)" "character(0)" "character(0)" "character(0)"
```

Now it works, but erase all the metadata (in this case the doc names). There is a way to mantain the metadata, or to save and then restore them?

Comment: I thought that myself, but I did not found it either in VectorSource() nor in Corpus() or in tm_map() help file.

Comment: Upon calling  `TermDocumentMatrix`, I get `Error in UseMethod("meta", x) : `

Comment: I'm interested to know if when you used the same name `myCorpus` in successive assignments, if it may have changed your data attributes, because that's an attributes check function `inherits`

Comment: Thank you Richard. I found a solution myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DocumentTermMatrix error on Corpus argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191728/documenttermmatrix-error-on-corpus-argument)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it.

The line:

```
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, PlainTextDocument)
```

solves the problem but erase the metadata.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771621/203692) that explain a better way to use tm_map(). I just have to substitute:

```
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, tolower)
```

with:

```
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
```

And all works!