# Add new document to term document matrix in R

Tags: r, text-mining, information-retrieval, term-document-matrix

I have `term document matrix` before and want to add `new document` to `that term document matrix`, in another way it can say to join two document matrix.

My term document matrix is :

```
     Docs
Term   1
eat    7
food   2
run    2
sick   3
```

Then another document is `watch football match and eat food`

After the process, i want my term document matrix to be :

```
         Docs
Term     1   2
eat      7   1
food     2   1
run      2   0
sick     3   0
watch    0   1
football 0   1
match    0   1
and      0   1
```

I've tried this :

```
library("SnowballC")
library("NLP")
library("tm")
library("lsa")

                   #mytermdm (term document matrix i have before)

text2 <- "watch fottball match and eat food"
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text2))

tdm2 <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control = list
                         (removeNumbers = TRUE, 
                         removePunctuation = TRUE, 
                         stopwords=stopwords_en, 
                         stemming=TRUE)
)
mytdm3 <- c(mytermdm,tdm2)
inspect(mytdm3)
```

I get this :

```
TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 7, document:2)

Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(x,terms,doc)`
    Repeated indices currently no allowed.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410866/r-inspect-document-term-matrix-results-in-error-repeated-indices-currently-not

Comment: still confused, in that question, we know the text file, then make tdm based on the text, in my question, I just know the text of the second file you want to put in tdm. Simply put, I loaded tdm, then made tdm which is a combination of previous tdm with the second text

Comment: I have solved it, before combine two document matrix, I replace docs names in tdm2 using :

`colnames(tdm2) <- as.numeric(max(colnames(mytermdm)))+1` and then combine it

Comment: @Hilfit19, that is one of the solutions. you can also adjust the dimnames in mytdm3 or even in the beginning with corpus and meta functions. If you want I can write a big answer that touches all of the options.

Comment: No @phiver thank for your kindness

Comment: You can post that as a solution

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it, before combine two term document matrix, I replace docs names in tdm2. So, the full algoritm :

```
library("SnowballC")
library("NLP")
library("tm")
library("lsa")

#mytermdm (term document matrix i have before)

text2 <- "watch fottball match and eat food"
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text2))

tdm2 <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control = list
                     (removeNumbers = TRUE, 
                     removePunctuation = TRUE, 
                     stopwords=stopwords_en, 
                     stemming=TRUE)
)

colnames(tdm2) <- as.numeric(max(colnames(mytermdm)))+1     #my add solution 


mytdm3 <- c(mytermdm,tdm2)
inspect(mytdm3)
```