# termdocumentmatrix raises error in R

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
library(tm)
text<-readLines("anyText.txt")
corpus<-Corpus(VectorSource(text))
corpus<-tm_map(corpus,content_transformer(tolower))
inspect(corpus)
corpus<-tm_map(corpus,removePunctuation)
stopwords<-c(stopwords('english'),"available","via")
corpus<-tm_map(corpus,removeWords,stopwords)
tempCorpus<-corpus
inspect(tempCorpus)
library(ctv)
library(SnowballC)
corpus<-tm_map(corpus,stemDocument)
inspect(corpus)
corpusT<- tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
corpusT<-tm_map(corpusT,stemCompletion,dictionary=tempCorpus)
dtm<-TermDocumentMatrix(corpusT,control=list(minWordLength=1))
```

but I got the error:

```
   Error: inherits(doc, "TextDocument") is not TRUE
```

I found that when I comment the line:

```
corpusT<-tm_map(corpusT,stemCompletion,dictionary=tempCorpus)
```

the program works fine, but for what I know that last line is for updating the list of steem words with the ones I got in tempCorpus so I need it.

How can I correct that error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DocumentTermMatrix error on Corpus argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191728/documenttermmatrix-error-on-corpus-argument)

Answer (score 2):

The code `corpusT<-tm_map(corpusT,stemCompletion,dictionary=tempCorpus)` is not returning the TextDocuments so you are getting an error.

Adding the code `corpusT<- tm_map(corpusT, PlainTextDocument)` before creating dtm and after `stemCompletion` should fix the issue.

Your last part of the code should look as below:

```
inspect(corpus)
corpusT<-tm_map(corpus,stemCompletion,dictionary=tempCorpus)
corpusT<- tm_map(corpusT, PlainTextDocument)
dtm<-TermDocumentMatrix(corpusT,control=list(minWordLength=1))
```

For additional info please refer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24206825/3858156

Comment: your solution is wrong and it has been posted before the issue, when one uses PlainTextDocument it erases the metadata

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the answer. I meant `PlainTextDocument` should be run after `stemCompletion` and before `dtm`. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, but the error is still there, the metadata gets deleted

Comment: Welcome, is it possible to give more information on meta data getting deleted and what exactly you are looking for in meta data?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I need to wrap all functions passed into tm_map in content_transformer, as you did with tolower.  Then the error goes away.

Comment: Not suggesting something like:  `corpusT <- tm_map(corpusT, content_transformer(PlainTextDocument))`. That doesn't work.