# How to complete a stemmed corpus from a dictionary using stemCompletion function (tm package)

Tags: r, tm

I am having a trouble in the tm package of R. I am using 0.6.2 version. Following question (2 different errors) has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191728/documenttermmatrix-error-on-corpus-argument) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771165/r-project-no-applicable-method-for-meta-applied-to-an-object-of-class-charact) but still producing an error after using the posted solution. Please click [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2YVITpwU9nPTjdDLUV4YXJFSlU/view?usp=sharing) to download the dataset (93 rows only). It's a reproducible example.
the two errors are below:

1. **(Resolved)** Error in UseMethod("meta", x) : 
   no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "character"
2. Error: inherits(doc, "TextDocument") is not TRUE
3. tm_map(ds.corpus, PlainTextDocument) does not create a plain text document in this case. 
   inherits(ds.cleanCorpus, "TextDocument") # returns FALSE

please tell me what is wrong in my approach.

--

```
  # Data import
    df.imp<- read.csv("Phone2_Sample100_NegPos.csv", header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)

   ##### Data Pre-Processing 

        install.packages("tm")
    require(tm)  

    ds.corpus<- Corpus(VectorSource(df.imp$Content))

    ds.corpus<- tm_map(ds.corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
    ds.corpus<- tm_map(ds.corpus, content_transformer(removePunctuation))
    ds.corpus<- tm_map(ds.corpus, content_transformer(removeNumbers))
    removeURL<- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)
    ds.corpus<- tm_map(ds.corpus,removeURL)

    stopwords.default<- stopwords("english")
    stopWordsNotDeleted<- c("isn't" ,     "aren't" ,    "wasn't" ,    "weren't"   , "hasn't"    ,
                            "haven't" ,   "hadn't"  ,   "doesn't" ,   "don't"      ,"didn't"    ,
                            "won't"   ,   "wouldn't",   "shan't"  ,   "shouldn't",  "can't"     ,
                            "cannot"    , "couldn't"  , "mustn't", "but","no", "nor", "not", "too", "very")

    stopWord.new<- stopwords.default[! stopwords.default %in% stopWordsNotDeleted] ## new Stopwords list
    ds.corpus<- tm_map(ds.corpus, removeWords, stopWord.new )

    copy<- ds.corpus ## creating a copy to be used as a dictionary

    ds.corpus<- tm_map(ds.corpus, stemDocument)

    ## error Statement #1
    ds.corpus<-  stemCompletion(ds.corpus, dictionary = copy) 
    ## Error in UseMethod("meta", x) : no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "character"




    ds.cleanCorpus<- tm_map(ds.corpus, PlainTextDocument) ## creating plain text document

    class(ds.cleanCorpus) ## output is VCorpus" "Corpus".  what it should be??

    ## error Statement #2
    tdm<- TermDocumentMatrix(ds.corpus) ## creating  term document matrix 

    inherits(ds.cleanCorpus, "TextDocument") ## returns FALSE
```

**Update:** 
Figured out first error, that the stemCompletion method's x parameter should be a character vector and dictionary could be either a corpus or character vector. However, when I tried it on first document (character vector) of ds.corpus, as below, stemmed words were not completed and output is just the stemmed character vector like before.

```
stemCompletion(ds.corpus[[1]]$content, dictionary = copy)
```

So now my main question is "**How to complete a stemmed corpus from a dictionary (tm package)?**" The stemCompletion method doesn't seems working (on a character vector). Secondly, how can I complete the stemming of an entire corpus, should I use a for loop for each document of the corpus's content?

Comment: Hmm have a look at `?stemCompletion`. In `stemCompletion(ds.corpus,stemCompletion, dictionary = copy)` you are passing an object of type `Corpus` to an argument that should be of type `character`, and... welll... I dunno where the 2nd argument `stemCompletion` should go. Maybe you should clarify what you are trying to accomplish...?

Comment: I am just making myself comfortable with the functions of tm package. Here, I am performing basic data pre-processing before building out a model. Please check out the links in the question to get a better reference. @MrFlick

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things you need to change

1. When you use a custom function you need to use content_transformer

   removeURL<- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)

   ds.corpus<- tm_map(ds.corpus,content_transformer(removeURL))
2. The purpose of the function stemCompletion is to try to complete a stemmed word https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming based on a dictionary. The stemmed words need to be a character vector and dictionary can be a corpus.

   x <- c("compan", "entit", "suppl")
   stemCompletion(x, copy)

output:

```
 compan       entit       suppl
```

"companies"          ""  "supplies"

**Code to create Document Term Matrix**

```
# Data import
df.imp<- read.csv("data/Phone2_Sample100_NegPos.csv", header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)

##### Data Pre-Processing 

#install.packages("tm")
require(tm)  

ds.corpus<- Corpus(VectorSource(df.imp$Content))

ds.corpus<- tm_map(ds.corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
ds.corpus<- tm_map(ds.corpus, content_transformer(removePunctuation))
ds.corpus<- tm_map(ds.corpus, content_transformer(removeNumbers))
removeURL<- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)
ds.corpus<- tm_map(ds.corpus,content_transformer(removeURL))


stopwords.default<- stopwords("english")
stopWordsNotDeleted<- c("isn't" ,     "aren't" ,    "wasn't" ,    "weren't"   , "hasn't"    ,
                        "haven't" ,   "hadn't"  ,   "doesn't" ,   "don't"      ,"didn't"    ,
                        "won't"   ,   "wouldn't",   "shan't"  ,   "shouldn't",  "can't"     ,
                        "cannot"    , "couldn't"  , "mustn't", "but","no", "nor", "not", "too", "very")

stopWord.new<- stopwords.default[! stopwords.default %in% stopWordsNotDeleted] ## new Stopwords list
ds.corpus<- tm_map(ds.corpus, removeWords, stopWord.new )

tdm<- TermDocumentMatrix(ds.corpus)
```

## Example to  complete stemmed words

```
copy<- ds.corpus ## creating a copy to be used as a dictionary
x <- c("compan", "entit", "suppl")
stemCompletion(x, copy)
```

Comment: @freetiger if this answers your question kindly accept the answer.

Comment: @amitkb3 why is is necessary to create a copy? e.g. why can one not do stemCompletion(x, ds.corpus) ?

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you have found the solution already. I have been informed by this post [stemCompletion is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206049/stemcompletion-is-not-working)
and I believe it solves your second questions of "How to complete a stemmed corpus from a dictionary (tm package)?" (as well as mine, which is similar to yours). Specifically, you can try the following code:

```
    stem_completion <- tm_map(ds.corpus, 
                       content_transformer(function(x, d)
                         paste(stemCompletion(strsplit(stemDocument(x), ' ')[[1]], d), 
                               collapse = ' ')), d = copy)
```